# Prevent multiple findOne calls triggered by real time stream

Tags: node.js

I have a stream of events that roughly looks like this:

```
{ hash: 'XXXX', foo: 'bar }
```

On each hit, I gotta look up that hash in a db using mongoose

```
await Model.find({hash: XXX})
```

Sometimes, I get hit with a bunch of events that share the same hash and currently it triggers a bunch of `.find()` calls that essentially return the same thing.

How can I optimize this process and prevent `.find()` from being called multiple times if the hash is the same.

Comment: how does the stream of events looks like? like an array of { hash: 'XXXX', foo: 'bar } ?

Comment: it will be great if you share the piece of code you're working on

Comment: I failed to mentioned that this "stream" is actually being triggered by mongoose Collection.watch.on('change') so each "hit" is basically an object { hash: 'XXXX', foo: 'bar }

Comment: you can get the unique list of hashes by: 
uniqueHashes = new Set(...streamArray.map(item=>item.hash))
then call Model.find where hash in uniqueHashes filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways you could potentially do this. If the list is not long, keep an array of these objects with the DB result. Search the array before doing the DB query.

```
// Disclaimer: This is total pseudocode - not tested in REPL or anything :)
//
// hashResults as an array of objects like:
// { hash: XXX, data: obj }

let hashResults = [];

const getHashValue = async (hash) => {
  const result = hashResults.find(r => r.hash === hash)
  if (result) {
    return result.data;
  } else {
    // Do the DB lookup
    const data = await Model.find({ hash });

    // add to the cache of results
    hashResults.push({ hash, data });

    return data;
  }
}

// However you are looping for the hashes... assuming you have an array of them.
for(h in hashes) {
  const val = await getHashValue(h);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Ended up using similar solution!